# GraphServiceClient, Create ContentVersions to intune with GraphServiceClient

Tags: c#, .net-core, microsoft-graph-api

I'm having trouble creating a new ContentVersion - Right now I have created a new entry with this code.

```
var newItem = await client.DeviceAppManagement.MobileApps.Request().AddAsync(new Win32LobApp {});
```

But I can't find the method to create a new ContentVersion. I know the URL, but not the method to call. 
The URL to call is this

```
POST: https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/deviceAppManagement/mobileApps/{0}/microsoft.graph.win32LobApp/contentVersions
```

So far I have tried to clone the github project (https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-beta-sdk-dotnet) to see how it works, but without luck. And right now, I just don't know where to look.

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I solved it by doing it like this

```
ManagedMobileLobAppRequestBuilder builder = new ManagedMobileLobAppRequestBuilder($"{client.BaseUrl}/deviceAppManagement/mobileApps/{newItem.Id}/{newItem.ODataType.Substring(1)}", client);
var result = await builder.ContentVersions.Request().AddAsync(new MobileAppContent());
```

Not sure if this is the correct way of doing it, but it works!

Answer (score 0):

An alternative solution with a little less string concatenation:

```cs
var lobType = createAppResult.ODataType.Substring(1);
var baseUrl = client.DeviceAppManagement.MobileApps[appId].AppendSegmentToRequestUrl(lobType)
var lobRequestBuilder = new ManagedMobileLobAppRequestBuilder(baseUrl, client);
```